# How often are cgroup memory usage values refreshed?

Tags: memory, cgroups

I am wondering how often cgroup memory usage values are refreshed? Is there any parameter to tune it? I saw something similar for CPU, but not memory.

For example in this file:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/<cgroup-name>/memory.stat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no refresh, the values given when you read one of the cgroup files reflect the actual use at the time. You can see this in action by watching the `memory.stat` file, highlighting differences:

```
watch -d cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
```